Chat rate limit appears to be gone
Right now, you can post things in chat without any rate limit.
Proof:



(Notice the timestamps. I use an userscript but it's unrelated)

Also worth to mention we can post same message over and over, this used to be blocked as well. (At least in se.com chat - here it might still be blocked.)

It wasn't exactly blocked, but a cooldown was needed to post the same message over.

What was the rate-limit before? How do you know you just weren't fast enough?

@Starship https://i.sstatic.net/2fWb2BIM.png (source).

The rate limit isn't gone, just changed
The rate limit isn't gone, but it did change back in 2024-06, or so. I did some testing of the changed rate limits on 2024-06-17 in this room of 200 messages at the maximum rate, which was a few/several days after I first noticed the change. A userscript I have routinely sends my messages, which tend to be a few/several messages at a time, at (very near) the maximum rate, so I noticed it shortly after the change happened. The testing I've linked here shows an effective rate limit of 37.62 messages/minute over 200 messages.1
In comparison, I had previously done some testing on 2023-04-14 here of 2063 messages sent at the maximum rate. I've intended to update the "Chat" section of answer to: "The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide", as it was somewhat inaccurate, even prior to the more recent change.
The changed rate limit was helpful for SmokeDetector to handle a recent wave of spam
Due to the changed chat rate limit, SmokeDetector was able to keep up in chat with a recent intense wave of spam that lasted several hours. The more intense portion of the wave of spam was on [gis.se], but also affected other sites. The more intense part of this wave started on 2024-11-09 and continued into 2024-11-10. Being able to handle this spam wave was the reason the company temporarily changed the network-wide baseline allocation of flags from 10 to 100. The spammer is, as of 2024-11-24, still posting their spam, at a slower rate, but it's spread out to multiple sites on the Stack Exchange Network.
While this most recent wave of spam wasn't as intense as the wave of spam that resulted in SmokeDetector being more than 1 hour behind real time in posting spam as a result of the chat rate limit, SmokeDetector likely would have had a problem keeping up with real time during at least portions of the most recent wave of spam.
The change happened in a similar timeframe as Stack Exchange was actively working on changes for Charcoal and changing the chat rate limit was one of our requests.
In the timeframe that the chat rate limit change happened, I and other members of Charcoal were in discussions about changes Charcoal (the group running SmokeDetector and metasmoke) needed/wanted. One of our requests was loosening the chat rate limit. I do not affirmatively know that the change was intended, but given that the rate limit does still exist and is not just "gone", I've assumed that the change was intentional.

My testing doesn't, necessarily, demonstrate the actual maximum rate. The code I used for this testing waits for each POST request to complete prior to sending another request. When a response is received indicating that there's a rate limit, it waits the specified number of seconds prior to sending the next POST request.It *may* be possible to have a higher effective rate by having multiple POST requests in flight at the same time (but then message order isn't guaranteed, based on other testing). Doing so for the SE API has a substantial overall increase in throughput. However, chat isn't an interface that's intended for programmatic access, so it's unlikely to be configured similarly. I would expect that such a traffic pattern in chat of having multiple POST requests in flight at the same time is much more likely to be shut down hard by Cloudflare.
There was a short period when I did have multiple POST requests in flight at the same time, because Firefox was malfunctioning (restarting Firefox fixed it), and I did encounter rate limiting. I did not, however, characterize the rate limiting at that time, nor did I intentionally send any more than a "normal" number of messages.


Changed to e.g. 1000 per minute is by all means gone. Nitpicking, sure, but it's like the "temporary suspension" for 200 years. Anyway, while it's great that the company is helping, would be even better if it's not done in the shades but rather in public and announced somewhere. Ideally, feature request here on Meta Stack Exchange, tagged with chat, etc.

@ShadowWizard Given that the testing I linked to in this answer shows an effective rate of 37.62 messages/minute over 200 messages, claiming 1000/minute is a significant exaggeration.

My testing doesn't, necessarily, demonstrate the actual maximum rate. The code I used for this testing waits for each POST to complete prior to sending another request. It may be possible to have a higher effective rate by having multiple POST requests in flight at the same time (but then message order isn't guaranteed). Doing so for the SE API has a substantial overall increase in throughput. However, chat isn't an interface that's intended for programmatic access. It's unlikely to be configured similarly. Such traffic pattern in chat is much more likely to be shut down hard by Cloudflare.

I have been able to send 500 messages in 5 seconds using $.post and a for loop from DevTools, just FYI.

@PetəíŕdtheWizard To quibble a bit, chat indicates a difference in timestamps of 65 seconds between your "1" message and "496" message in that sequence (not the first "1" which you posted around that time, but the "1" which is associated with the sequence).

@Makyen I've started the JS loop from 2 to differentiate the script messages from my past ones. :) I know I could just do a --- between messages but it didn't come up in my head.

So, 59 seconds.

I'm pretty sure this was not an intentional change, but it's good that it helped  I have an idea what caused this though. I'll investigate, but I'll keep Smoky's need in mind.

@balpha IMHO, letting users flood chat isn't a good idea. Even if "only" 100 messages per minute, it's way too much and can't be normal usage. If there would be a way to exclude specific users from the rate limit it would be ideal, and Smokey will be able to post even 1000 spam reports in a minute, if required.

@ShadowWizard Agree, that's what I meant.
